# Does car need to be driven rather than idle to ensure battery recharged?

Tags: battery

My car is inactive for months at a time.  I started it up and just left it running idle for 30 minutes.  Would that be sufficient to recharge the battery or does it need to actually be running at higher revs for it to be recharged?

Comment: Search on here - has been asked before and recently.

Answer (score 2):

> My car is inactive for months at a time. I started it up and just left it running idle for 30 minutes.

Alternator at idle does not produce maximum power. However, your battery is not typically charged at maximum power. Leave all the electrical accessories off (especially heated steering wheel, seats, windows etc), lights too if you can, so you will save 10 amperes of current that can be used for charging.

I mean, if the lights take 10 amperes, and they work at idle, by turning off the lights you will get the 10 amperes for charging the battery. That's plenty.

Another issue might be that 30 minutes might be too short for a car that has been inactive for months. The batteries slowly develop sulfation, which reduces the charging rate. So, this might mean that revving up the engine or starting to drive around may not help you at all if the battery does not accept charge quickly enough! Typically, chargers will charge the battery in 4 hours or so, faster charge is not recommended.

I would heavily recommend to invest in a charger capable of charging your battery in 4 hours and the leaving it on charge for 4 hours. If not possible, then you just need to idle it more often, not after months of non-use, but preferably twice a month. Or, you can just leave it idling for 4 hours. Don't do that without being nearby and checking the car often to see it won't overheat!

Also, do purchase a multimeter. Measure your battery voltage after many hours of rest, to see if it's fully charged or not.

Comment: After purchasing the multimeter, learn how to use it.

Comment: @SolarMike Agreed. Especially, learn why not measure the amperage capacity of a battery by selecting the current measurement mode...

Answer (score 2):

**Don't just idle the car**, unless your owner's manual says that's alright (it probably does not).  Go ahead and drive it somewhere; anywhere; doesn't need to be far. This will also clear out the engine of deposits that will accumulate if you merely idle it.

Turn off all engine devices and accessories, including A/C, blower, wipers, headlights, seat heaters etc. Obviously don't do this on a rainy day, when you need all that to drive around safely :)  It's OK to run the heater with the blower on low/medium, as long as AC/Defrost is off.  If you need cooling, open the windows!

Further, you should drive it enough to rotate the fuel in the tank, so you're not keeping (much) fuel longer than a year or so.  Paradoxically, it's also best to keep the tank *full* to reduce condensation.   If you're not using a tankful a year, contemplate Uber, Hertz or ZipCar, and sell the car.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before and it should be ok, depends on condition of battery and alternator, if you have a volt meter you could check the alternator is supplying between 13.6 and 14.4 volts.
If you just leave it sitting for months at a time, I would move the car back and forth a little to make sure the brakes don't seize, and before switching it off, running the engine for 1 minute at 2000+ rpm would help the lubrication of the engine.
If there is an alarm then disconnecting the battery or adding a solar trickle charger would help hold the charge.

Answer (score 0):

I fitted a larger alternator to my vehicle to be able to charge other people’s batteries in an emergency.

I fitted a hand throttle mechanism to get above idle - used 2000rpm. This meant the alternator delivered full power. It helps to have an understanding of the pulley ratios between the engine and alternator. It is usually around 2 to 3.

Aslo used the hand throttle to drive the saw bench but that is another story.